What does the 7 segment number mean on my CRT monitor?
I am a 20 year old electrical engineering student who loves old tech. I recently got a new CRT to replace my old one for my setup but this one has a small 7 segment display at the bottom left of the monitor.
The monitor is a Darius with the (I can only assume) model number HRN-14LR. Could someone give me some information on this monitor and what the 7 segment display means?


Is it 7 all the time or does it change under various conditions?

It changes, but hard to tell what causes it to change. The question was answered down below and after some testing, I can confirm the answer is correct.

It's indicating the display resolution using an approximation of the number of vertical scanlines. So 7 means you are probably running in 1024x768. It's not entirely consistent because some modes are in the same range, so for example 5=640x480 because 4 was already taken for 640x400.
Edit: The list of modes from the user manual


This is more complete than my semi-compiled answer.  Source for the info?

@dave From the regular user manual. There are scans for the HRN-14LR on schematicsforfree.com in the Monitors - CRT subfolder in the Video folder. The first file you'll find is the user manual and the second file is the same service manual you were looking at.

Is that an "approximation of the number of vertical scanlines" or simply a number the manufacturer arbitrarily chose to correlate with the number of scanlines?

@AmazonDiesInDarkness The table in David's screen grab from the manual has the header "LED DISPLAY SHOWS APPROXMATED [sic] SCANNING LINES"

This may ponder into a separate question (which I don't have time to write at the moment), but I wonder, what was the use of this? Why was this such an important info that it warranted a separate display showing it all the time?

It's a strange approximation — sometimes rounding down, sometimes up…  You might also think that, with 9 different modes, they could assign a different digit to each rather than needlessly using duplicate and triplicate values.

@Neinstein Current displays will normally show the current resolution if you activate the on screen display menu, and I have had occasional reason to need that information when OS, drivers and video converter hardware was being ambiguous about actual vs claimed display modes. That said suspect this LED display was left over from design/development of the unit (to confirm it was locking to correct settings) that someone decided to leave in, rather than a feature that was added due user demand.

@Neinstein Marketing: It looks complicated and has nerd appeal. Some high-end displays even had a mini LCD in the bezel that displayed this information and did the same thing as modern on-screen displays in adjusting settings.

Guess from 30 seconds with google - it's the video mode.
See fig 5-6 in the service manual.
The meaning of '7' is however not obvious from the service manual.
